# HDMI Audio Issue Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, video, hdmi

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from 21.10 today. After upgrade, HDMI Audio setting is not playing any sound through TV Speakers. Video playback on Plex is also broken, stopping and starting and very jumpy. I assumed it was an issue with the upgrade, so I did a clean install of 22.04. Everything works as expected when using built in speakers, Plex video plays correctly and has sound. As soon as I change to HDMI audio output, I no longer get sound and playback on Plex breaks. This is a Dell 6540 laptop. I have swapped HDMI cables and get the same result. No issues with this laptop on 21.04 or 21.10.

Comment: One wonders how it passed QC with this kinda bug...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have fixed this bug here.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1970050

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"
```

Save file and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: What's the meaning of this - `intel_iommu=on,igfx_off` ? What does it do?

Comment: @dakini As far as I can tell, it [turns off the integrated graphics engine](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/Intel-IOMMU.txt). It solved the issue, but not exaclty an ideal solution.

Comment: How is that even a solution? It is like closing your eyes to be able to hear...

Comment: For whatever it's worth this did not bring back the HDMI output device on 22.10. In summary, if you're looking for an even worse audio experience, update to 22.10 and neither your integrated nor HDMI speakers will work...

Comment: Not enough credibility to answer, (up for grabs) ... I had to enable wireplumber.  See https://gist.github.com/the-spyke/2de98b22ff4f978ebf0650c90e82027e .

Answer (score 1):

I had no HDMI Audio output after a clean install of 22.04 LTS. Upgrading from 20.04, which had no problems with HDMI Audio. I run 22.04 on a Intel DH87RL with a 4770 (Haswell) CPU.

The GRUB edit that is reported to correct no HDMI audio output gave me a clue to try a different approach.

IOMMU requires CPU virtualization support. I toggled OFF 2 UEFI/BIOS settings for virtualization support on my motherboard.

This corrected my HDMI Audio issue.

I did a clean install of the 22.04 OS before I tested the HDMI Audio output.

The Pulseaudio pavucontrol app allowed me to "lock in" my HDMI audio config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my I5 Haswell.
You'll need to edit grub.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

  Change:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  To:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"

sudo update-grub
reboot
```