# Ubuntu 22.04 - No Sound via HDMI / DisplayPort

Tags: sound, hdmi

As per the title, I get no sound following a fresh install of 22.04. In another partition I have Zorin OS 16 and it works just fine. I followed the instructions in this post [HDMI Audio Issue Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04) but it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated. Also I am most definitely a noob. I have enough knowledge to move away from Windows & install the os, follow instructions etc. but am at loss when it comes to troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia graphics and forget to tick the option to install 3rd party drivers, etc.? If so you can install them now.

Comment: See this post here, the reported bug and solution could be your issue (I had it on my system on upgrade to 22.04). And also someone else posted a different solution here too so a couple of things to try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Hi, thank you both your your replies. @ChanganAuto I have Intel HD Graphics 4600. In Software & Updates app I have "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted) ticked.

Comment: @codlord yes, thank you. Have seen that linked and have applied all of the suggested changes. Unfortunately none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Strong hint regarding Ubuntu hdmi problem: I had 20.04 working with sound ONLY through the NVIDIA monitor, and got no sound at all when installing 22.04.

Somebody gave a very useful hint about looking at UEFI BIOS, Advanced, Onboard Devices Configuration: HD Audio Controller (enabled!), Front Panel Type: HD Audio (no go) but AC97 works!

SPDIF Out Type: SPDIF works, HDMI ? Save changes & reset.

Well, doing this I suddenly had messed up my 20.04. Reason: in Setup -> Sound, Output Device: HDMI/DisplayPort2 - GK208 HDMI/DP worked, but Output Device: HDMI/Display Port - GK208 etc does not. To get the DisplayPort2 in both partitions, another hint was useful: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ; reboot. Alsamixer and pavucontrol never helped.

Now I still would like to have audio optionally through external speakers, and headphones ...

Comment: Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and VIA sound card stopped working, HDMI audio only. As recommended by Göran Schultz I ran sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and restarted. Problem solved!

Comment: @tom-197 That command installs Nvidia drivers that are usually required for proper *HDMI* audio but have absolutely NOTHING to do with the onboard audio device, VIA or any other,

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit too optimistic above with the sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. My 20.04 which had worked for years with only occasional mouse-movement freeze, now started frequent mouse-click freeze (moves but no action). askubuntu.com/questions/1269473/ubuntu-20-04-freeze suggests (on a TTY terminal, ctrl-alt-F2) to do sudo apt-get purge nvidia*, and some more steps before reboot. Well, rare mouse-movement freeze has returned, but not the mouse-click freeze. I strongly suspect the nvidia drivers to be the culprit (timing issues - mostly when I have many windows/tabs open) for both mouse problems and non-hdmi audio funnies (on the Setup -> Sound I even see that live sound is delivered somewhere, I just can't get it out).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241676)