Ubuntu 24.04 no HDMI audio
I just did a clean install of 24.04 on a system that did hdmi audio on 23.10. Headphone jack audio works as does bluetooth. The hdmi video is fine, just no audio.
Suggestions?

of possible help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04

Why is this duplicate? 24.04 != 22.04. my audio works fine in 22.04 but after installing 24.04 it's not working anymore. 22.04 uses pulseaudio while 24.04 uses pipewire.

@shunz19 the solution that OP posted as an answer is the same as the one in the dupe. If you have the same problem but it doesn't work for you, then post a new question with more details (what hardware you're using, relevant log messages from dmesg or pipewire logs, etc.). Just being a different release doesn't make it not a dupe.

changing model in sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi helps me

check my full answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1533282/2026350

I found a similar problem in postings for older releases. Adding:
intel_iommu=on,igfx_off

to /etc/default/grub is a workaround.

doesn't solve my HDMI sound in 24.04 :-(
